# Maximum width of <pre>, not wrap text

Tags: html, pre

I am using `<pre>` tag in my html, it's allocating the whole width of the page, while I need to make it just as long as the text can be. Note that my text is too short, but the `<pre>` is taking the whole width of the page, so am not looking into wrapping my text to another line as some questions on SO mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From W3Schools:

> The width attribute of `<pre>` is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS
> instead.
>
> ```
> CSS syntax: <div style="width:200px;overflow:auto"><pre>Some
> text</pre></div>
> ```
>
> [CSS Example: Pre-formatted text with a fixed width](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pre_width_css)

Source: [HTML PRE width Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_pre_width.asp)

Although, as you have pointed out, this is not dynamic. Try these two methods:

```
pre {display:table; margin:auto;}
```

or

```
<pre style="border: 1px solid black; margin:auto; display:inline-block;">
    aaa
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    ccc
</pre>
```

Source: [Auto width for PRE element, using CSS?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.infosystems.www.authoring.stylesheets/oic0qfzsep8)

Comment: But can't I make it dynamic, whatever text it contains to stretch automatically? As I would have many <pre>.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't see that requirement. Apologies. Have updated answer with two new methods.

Comment: Inline-block did it :)

Comment: Excellent. Glad to have helped :-)